# Guids not found in firebird table

Tags: .net, linq, firebird, guid, entity-framework-6

I have a table which is defined as

```
CREATE TABLE "Test1"
(
  ID Char(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS NOT NULL,
  "StartedAt" Timestamp NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_Test1" PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

I insert records with an GUID as ID. I use Entitiy Framework 6 to read and insert the records.

When I use the following LINQ code to get data from the table, I got nothing:

```
var dbData = repo.Select(record => parentSource.Contains(record.ID))
.OrderBy(record => record.TimeStamp);
```

parentSource is a List< Guid > and contains some guids. repo is my database context. When I take a look at the generated SQL, I get this:

```
SELECT 
"B"."ID" AS "ID", 
"B"."StartedAt" AS "StartedAt", 
FROM "Test1" AS "B"
WHERE "B"."ID" IN (CHAR_TO_UUID('60c78366-e6d2-4cba-b830-27ad0e4d06f2'),CHAR_TO_UUID('dbfa36ed-ec81-4914-ad70-4a0dd0677fdd'))
```

You can see that I search for two guids in the table and both guids exists in the table. But they are not found. When I compare the output of the CHAR_TO_UUID function I got a different value as that what is generated in the ID column when I insert the records.
So, how to get this code working?

Edit1:
Firebird database is 2.5
.net provider is 4.0

Values in column ID in the table

```
ed36fadb81ec1449ad704a0dd0677fdd
6683c760d2e6ba4cb83027ad0e4d06f2
```

output of char_to_uuid is

```
dbfa36edec814914ad704a0dd0677fdd
60c78366e6d24cbab83027ad0e4d06f2
```

The two guids are the same, so they should be found by the linq code above. As I can see, the guids are partly the same. The first 4 bytes are in reverse order and the next 2 x 2 bytes too.

Comment: Could you show the actual value in the database, the output of `CHAR_TO_UUID` in hex, and the result of `UUID_TO_CHAR` of the the value in the database. Also: exact Firebird version.

Comment: firebird is 2.5, .net provider 4.0, Value in db = ed36fadb81ec1449ad704a0dd0677fdd and 6683c760d2e6ba4cb83027ad0e4d06f2, output of char_to_uuid is 60c78366e6d24cbab83027ad0e4d06f2 and dbfa36edec814914ad704a0dd0677fdd. The two guids are the same, so normally they should be found by the linq code above.

Comment: I'd suggest to include that in your question. Are you sure all the guids in `parentSource` are actually in the database?

Comment: yes, I am sure. If I use Where in a linq statement, they get found. I edited my question above.

Comment: It is probably related to this bug in the Firebird .NET provider : http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-509

Comment: I changed the provider as described in the bug ticket and now it works. I had to change the conversion from byte[] to Guid and from Guid to Guid.